# Trouble Proving Invertability

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing, mathematical-modeling

I have this theorem.

So if A is a nonnegative matrix, then the following conditions are equivalent.

1. $(I-A)^{-1}$ exists and is non-negative
2. There is a non-negative vector $\vec{x}$ so that $(I-A)\vec{x}$ is positive (that is, all entries of $(I-A)\vec{x}$ are positive)

I have proved that 1 implies 2, but I am getting stuck on 2 implies 1.

Here's what I have for 1 implies 2. First we will start with 1 $\rightarrow$ 2. So we assume the first condition to be true, meaning that $(I-A)^{-1}$ exists and is non-negative. By definition $\vec{x}$ can be solved for using the equation $\vec{x} = (I-A)^{-1}\vec{b}$. Additionally, it is known that $\vec{b}$ cannot contain negative values as the external demand can only be positive. Using these two pieces of information, it can be seen that $\vec{x}$ must be positive, as only positive numbers are being used in its calculation. Now, the equation can be modified to solve for $\vec{b}$, giving $(I-A)\vec{x}=\vec{b}$ since we know that $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{b}$ are non-negative we can conclude that there is some non-negative vector $\vec{x}$ such that all the values of $(I-A)\vec{x}$ are positive.

Any help on 2 implies 1 would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: An observation: with diagonal similarity, the case where $x$ is positive can be further reduced to the case where $x = (1,\dots,1)$.

Comment: Note also that because of the Perron Frobenius theorem and because of the infinite series
$$
(I - A)^{-1} = I + A + A^2 + \cdots,
$$
it would suffices to show that $A$ has maximal positive eigenvalue less than $1$.

Comment: This might be helpful: in the case where $A$ is irreducible and aperiodic, let $\lambda$ denote the maximum positive eigenvalue of $A$, and let $v$ denote an associated non-negative eigenvector. We know that $(I - A)x$ is positive. It follows that for all $k$, $(I - A)(\lambda^{-k} A^kx)$ is non-negative. However, $\lim_{k \to \infty}\lambda^{-k} A^kx =  v$, so we can conclude that $(I - A)v = (1 - \lambda)v$ is non-negative, so that $\lambda \leq 1$.

Comment: In your proof, how did you conclude that $x = (I - A)^{-1}b$ is positive as opposed to merely non-negative? And what do you mean by "external demand"?

Comment: Here is a correct proof for $1 \implies 2$: take $b = (1,\dots,1)$ and $x = (I - A)^{-1}b$. $b$ is positive, and because $(I - A)^{-1}$ is non-negative, $x = (I - A)^{-1}b$ must be non-negative. Also, we indeed have $(I - A)x = b$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom This proof is for a theorem about the Leontief Input-Output Model which models supply and demand for a multi-industry system. The $\vec{b}$ represents the external demand which can only be positive values. In your case is b just ones or is it any real nonnegative value?

Comment: All we need to do to make my proof work is pick a $b$ with **positive** (as opposed to non-negative) entries. $b = (1,\dots,1)$ is one such vector.

Comment: My point was that even if $b$ has positive entries and $(I - A)^{-1}$ is non-negative, it does **not** necessarily follow that $(I - A)^{-1}b$ is positive. Regarding the differences between are proofs: note that in general, the best way to prove that a particular object exists is to provide a concrete example of such an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proof of $1 \implies 2$:

Let $e = (1,\dots,1)^T$. First, we show that there is necessarily a **positive** vector $x'$ for which $(I - A)x'$ is positive. In particular, we note that $\lim_{t \to 0^+}(I - A)(x + te)$ is positive. It follows that there exists a $t > 0$ for which $x' = x + te$ is such that $(I - A)x'$ is positive, and for this $t$, $x'$ is clearly positive.

Let $D = \operatorname{diag}(x')$. We have
$$
0 < D^{-1}(I - A)x' = D^{-1}(I - A)D(D^{-1}x') = (I - D^{-1}AD)(D^{-1}x') =  (I - B)e
$$
where $B = D^{-1}AD$.  We see that $B$ is a matrix for which $(I - B)e$ is positive. That is, we have
$$
0 < (I - B)e \implies Be < e.
$$
Thus, $B$ is a matrix for which all row-sums are at strictly less than $1$. We note that
$$
\rho(B) = \lambda_{\max}(B) \leq \|B\|_\infty = \max_{i=1,\dots,n} \sum_{j=1}^n |b_{ij}| < 1.
$$
Here, $\rho$ denotes the spectral radius and $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ denotes the [induced $\infty$-norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Special_cases).  Because $\rho(B) < 1$, it follows that the "Neumann series" $(I - B)^{-1} = \sum_{i=0}^\infty B^i$ converges. We then see that because $B$ is non-negative, this sum and hence $(I - B)^{-1}$ must be non-negative.

We can conclude that $(I - A)^{-1} = D(I - B)^{-1}D^{-1}$ is also non-negative, which was what we wanted.

Comment: It's *Neumann series*, not *von Neumann series*. It is named after Carl Neumann rather than John von Neumann.

Comment: @user1551 thanks for the correction. I also recently learned that Friedrich Schur and Issai Schur are distinct (unrelated, I think) people; math needs more surnames